# Loop through Vue b-table rows

Tags: javascript, vue.js, loops, bootstrap-vue

In Vue bootstrap, a b-table has a list (unknown length) of rows. A remove button should only appear if the email in the row matches the email of the current logged in user. This currently works if it is only checking one row.

```
<b-table
    :items="selectedGrant.interested_agencies"
    :fields="interestedAgenciesFields"
  >
  <template #cell(actions)="row">
    <b-row v-if="loggedInUser.email === selectedGrant.interested_agencies[0]['user_email']">
      <b-button variant="danger" class="mr-1" size="sm" @click="unmarkGrantAsInterested(row)">
        <b-icon icon="trash-fill" aria-hidden="true"></b-icon>
      </b-button>
    </b-row>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

How would I loop through all of the rows in the table?

Simply putting `selectedGrant.interested_agencies[row]['user_email']` does not go through each individual row. Most of what I have found for looping is for `li` lists and not the b-table. I have also tried incorporating a `v-for` in the `template` and another `b-row`, to no avail.

I have also tried a computing method in its place, but it did not work:

```
loop() {
   let i;
   let match;
   for (i = 0; i < this.interestedAgenciesFields.length(); i += 1) {
     if (this.loggedInUser.email === this.selectedGrant.interested_agencies[i].user_email) {
       match = true;
     } else {
       match = false;
     }
   }
   return match;
 },
```

Maybe it is something with javascript `.find()` method that could work? Again, I have enot found success with it.

Is there some way to loop through a b-table, whether it is inline of in a computing method, to check a specific value in each row? It should not be only checking one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to loop through all (or currently displayed) rows in the condition.
You're already inside the rows loop, because you're using a `#cell({key})` slot. What you probably want is to compare the current row's `user_email` to `loggedInUser.email`:

```html
<template #cell(actions)="row">
  <b-row v-if="loggedInUser.email === row.item.user_email">
    <b-button variant="danger" 
              class="mr-1"
              size="sm"
              @click="unmarkGrantAsInterested(row)">
      <b-icon icon="trash-fill" aria-hidden="true"></b-icon>
    </b-button>
  </b-row>
</template>
```

Docs [here](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#comp-ref-b-table-slots).

---

What's going on?
`#cell(actions)="row"` is a `#cell{{key}}` slot (where `{key}` is `actions`). If you press <kbd>Show scope</kbd> button in the docs, you'll be able to inspect the slot's structure (you named the slot `row` in your template - so you're looking at `row`'s structure). You likely want to use its `item` property, which is, actually, the raw data of current row, as an object.

You want to display the contents of `actions` cell on rows where `row.item.user_email` is equal to `loggedInUser.email`.

That's it.

Comment: wow that was much simpler than I thought, thank you!!!

Comment: @ASG, happy to help. Once you understand how slots work, they start making sense to the point where one might even consider them simple. But I haven't met anyone who understood them at first contact. We could say they're not intuitive.